# Can UIPath bot be setup and run on Mac OS

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity

Can UiPath work on Mac OS?
(i.e., A) can automations and bots be setup on a Mac and B) can they be ran on a Mac?)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A: You cannot currently run UiPath Studio or StudioX on a Mac.
- B: You CAN, if the automation was developed as a cross platform project, run an attended process through the UiPath assistant on MacOS.

This [link](https://www.uipath.com/community/rpa-community-blog/how-to-use-uipath-on-mac) will provide some more details on what you can and can't do with Macs currently, though it is dated 2021.